# Are there prayers that address Siva's entire family (Siva,Parvati,Ganesa and Kartikeya) collectively and/or individually?

Tags: shiva, family

The Ganesa and Kartikeya stories don't seem to intersect that much.  Has Siva's family been praised collectively in prayers?

Comment: I think, individually there are 'n' number of dedicated prayers to each one of them. Collectively might be interesting to see.

Comment: Internet is intresting: see [this](https://www.google.com/amp/s/mahaperiyavaa.blog/2015/01/29/shiva-parivar/amp/) could not find where that Dhynam is actually from.

Comment: You have it, @proxy.  I think the answer is yes.

Comment: @Proxy Mule kalpa drumasya ... is a dhyana sloka for Lord Shiva and not for the entire family. It is used for Shiva Puja only. See under Shiva in this link: http://yogauae.blogspot.com/2011/04/gems-of-yoga-brings-you-prayer-for.html

Comment: @Rickross Yes I am aware of that, however it was the one mentioning Ganesha, Kritikeya and parvati along with shiva.

Comment: Yes it is mentioning but the prayer (sloka) is still dedicated to Lord Shiva only. @Proxy

Comment: Yes yes! ofcourse! @Rickross